# Why am I getting a copy of sent Gmail from Android to the inbox of my Windows PC?

Tags: gmail, outlook, android

I send an email using Gmail app on my Android phone, and I get a copy of this very exact email in the inbox of Outlook 2010 on my Windows PC. It appears as if I got new mail, and when I check it I can see that it's not the reply I expected from the recipient, but my own email that I sent to the recipient from the phone few hours earlier. It's false alarm.

I have the same Gmail account set up in Outlook 2010 with POP3 sync as the one I use on my Android phone.

But when I navigate to www.gmail.com in my web browser, log in and check my inbox, I can't see this damn email. Instead, I see it under Sent mail (as expected). So why am I getting it to the inbox of Outlook 2010 then? How is this even possible if it's not even saved to the inbox of my Gmail account? Why is this happening and what can I do to fix this problem? Yes, I see it as a problem. Some people might even call it a "feature". If it is a feature of Gmail, I would like to know where I can change this strange behavior.

**Example:**

- I open Gmail on Android and compose a new message and send it from
  `my_mail@gmail.com` to `someone_else@gmail.com`.
- The message is sent and it shows up under "Sent" inside the Gmail
  app.
- When I check for new messages in Outlook 2010 on the PC, it brings up this
  email inside the "Inbox".
- Note! I only have `my_mail@gmail.com` configured in Outlook 2010.
- I don't have `someone_else@gmail.com` configured inside Outlook 2010. I
  don't even have access to someone_else@gmail.com since it's someone
  else's email!

So how can I be receiving emails from this address then to my Outlook inbox? This clearly indicates that it has to do with Google and my Gmail account, it has nothing to do with the Outlook 2010 email client. Also, this happens regardless of what the recipient (To) address is, it can be another Gmail address or a Yahoo address, a company email address, or whatever...

**Addendum**

Note that this is not a problem if I if I create a new email inside Outlook on the PC and send it off to someone. I don't get any "copies" (or whatever you want to call this) of the email I just sent out.

Comment: Since this is a problem you're seeing in Outlook, have you already had a look at [su] to see if someone else has also asked about this?

Comment: Yes, I didn't find anything relative, not even remotely related to this specific problem. If you find anything that might be of interest please post a link here in the comments.